# SSAS error - invalid attempt to read when reader is closed

Tags: mysql, ssas

I'm trying to run my SSAS project but I got an error. 
I'm using a MySQL database as my data source. 
I can connect and build the view, but when I create a dimension and I try to run it get this error:

> Errors in the high-level relational engine. Invalid attempt to Read
>   when reader is closed.. The exception was raised by the IDataReader
>   interface.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

In the connection to MySQL I set SQL SERVER MODE to True, otherwise I get a syntax error. I'm running on localhost.